# How to evaluate an open access journal?

Tags: publications, journals, ethics, open-access

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do you judge the quality of a journal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-you-judge-the-quality-of-a-journal)

How to evaluate the genuineness/authenticity, impact, significance & reputation of an open access journal? The prestigious journals have Impact factor & various indices, What about open access journals?

**EDIT:** Although a [previously](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-you-judge-the-quality-of-a-journal) asked question has garnered many responses, this question is only toward open access publishing.

Comment: this question is explicitly for open access.

Comment: I'm with @JukkaSuomela. There shouldn't be a difference.

Comment: @bobthejoe but there is a difference.

Comment: The economics are different for open vs. closed.  This means the "human physics" are nearly entirely incompatible with a non-open-access journal.  Look at communism/socialism vs. market economy.  The level and pervasiveness of tyranny is nearly asymptotically maximized in the former.  That is "different physics" for reviewers of the papers.

Answer (score 3):

In the same way you evaluate quality of a non-open access journal: who are the people on the editorial board, what kind of papers do they publish, etc.

Comment: Yep.  The quality of a journal is completely orthogonal to its business model.

Comment: I think this question has more merit than it is being given credit for.  Most of the journals that I currently have experience with are not open access but I can judge them based on extensive experience both as an author and a reader.  However as I become more interested in supporting and furthering open access, I am faced with having to evaluate journals that I have essentially no experience with (and neither do my peers).  This means that I can wait until I have acquired years of experience before I begin to publish in OA journals or look to use a different approach.

Comment: @DQdIM, I think that the correct question is how do you evaluate a new journal, not necessarily an OA journal. For instance, eLife is a brand new journal and there is no IF to measure or past experience, but from merely looking at their list of editors, you know it is going to be legit.