# How good are journal papers which ask you to pay x00$ to get published

Tags: phd, research-process, masters, ethics

I am looking to this journal -International Journal of Information and Education Technology and it seems they need 700$ to get my work included ,once it is approved.But is it a scammy journal .Has anybody heard of this practice before FYI ,here is the link http://www.ijiet.org/

Answer (score 4):

Asking for publishing charges *per se* is not necessarily a bad sign. It is almost unheard of in some fields, but perfectly normal in others.

A good indicator of bad quality and scammy journals is being on [Beall's list of predatory journals](http://scholarlyoa.com/2012/12/06/bealls-list-of-predatory-publishers-2013/). I'd suggest you to try and stay away from any publisher on that list, on general principle.

Apart from that, the usual criteria for judging a journal apply: do the other people in your field publish there, or cite their articles? Do you find good papers or reputable authors in the previous issues? Is anyone in the editorial board known to you? Is it indexed in databases and/or has a decent impact factor (with the possible caveat that databases and impact factor can be gamed, and have been in the past).

This question has been marked a duplicate of [this one](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-you-judge-the-quality-of-a-journal), so I suggest you check out the criteria there as well.

EDIT: fixed the part in which I thought this was on Beall's list, and turned this into a "general advice" answer.

Comment: ,its not on list.I cannot find it there.

Comment: Oops you're right, I misread the title for #64 in the journal list. My bad. I withdraw everything then (and I will probably delete this answer soon).

Comment: Didn't delete, but edited the answer instead.

Comment: Beal's list is not complete, AFAIK. There seem to be a lot of these kinds of journals around. I doubt anyone could keep up.