# Is it important to publish my article in a journal indexed on Thomson ISI?

Tags: publications, journals, bibliometrics, impact-factor

If a journal is not indexed this way, is it an academically honorable one?

Comment: Of course a non-ISI listed journal _can_ be an academically honorable one. Remember that ISI is just a service that indexes journal contents and it is employed to give journal a ranking number (oversimplifying). Your choice depends on several factors. First of all, which field are you in? Which country?

Comment: Related: http://academia.stackexchange.com/q/101/102

Comment: @dgraziotin Tourism Management. And I am from Iran but of course I am going to publish my work in English.

Comment: according to my experience publishing an article depends on which purpose you want to publish that paper and of course ISI journals have more value than other ones.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If we momentarily disregard from discussions regarding the cons of ISI and Thomson-Reuters who run the service etc. and focus on the usefulness of ISI indexed journals for ones career, the answer is yes, it is important at least to some extent. The importance is in part depending on your discipline since ISI indexing is not evenly distributed over disciplines. But generally speaking the ISI listing means the journal publishes papers that are referenced, which is an indication that it is research of some quality and importance.

This does not mean non-ISI-listed journals are not "honourable". But, when choosing a journal in which to publish, you need to make sure it is read by other in your field so that your research is seen and your ideas known by others. You should make a survey of journals that are of reference and if you find ISI-listed journals there is a reason to consider them if your papers fulfill their quality criteria because they will be  seen as prestigeous references when you are evaluated for a position etc.

Comment: I think this misses the actually important point: some bureaucracies won't count publications in non-ISI journals as "real."  If you want to get a job in a country with such a bureaucracy, that is your real issue.

Comment: @BenWebster Writing that as an answer would be valuable.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think "honourable" is the correct framework to think about.  My general understanding is that most reputable journals will be ISI indexed, and so if you are considering publishing in a journal which is not, you should look hard at whether it is legitimate, and whether people in your field will respect publications in it.  You should look at the same thing for ISI-indexed journals. 
 There are many journals which **are** ISI-indexed, and I have no reason to believe are not run legitimately, which I have never heard of, and which I would never recommend to someone I know as a place to publish (I don't want to pick on any particular one, but if you go to Web of Science and search for the name of your field, you will find plenty of them). An article in a journal I have never heard of makes a very poor impression to me on a CV, so it is worth researching more carefully what the "word of mouth" reputation of journals is in your field.