# How do I know the impact factor of a certain journal is true?

Tags: publications, journals, mathematics, publishers, impact-factor

I am new in publishing, I have never published a paper, and nowaday there are too many online journals. That made me suspicious about their reputation, and it is not easy for me as a beginner in publishing to decide whether they are faithful about their impact factor or not.

Let me be precise, I wonder if anybody know about [this](http://recentscience.org/ijms-international-journal-of-mathematical-sciences/) journal? it says it has impact factor 2.31, can anyone please confirm that?

If you believe this is not a correct place to ask this question can you please tell me where should I ask?

Comment: Recent Science (the published of said journal) is on Beall's list: http://scholarlyoa.com/publishers/ and could be considered predatory. Avoid. I also did not find the journal on Thomson Reuters master list (which is the "official" impact factor as I understand it). See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Journal_Citation_Reports

Comment: See http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-you-judge-the-quality-of-a-journal

Comment: I double checked. The journal "International Journal Of Mathematical Sciences" doesn't exist on JCR, hence has no impact factor assigned. There are 4 journals with "mathematical science" in the title, and the highest has impact factor of 1.52 (COMMUN MATH SCI). Avoid!