# Is Australian Business Deans Council Journal Quality List 2013 a good metric to ascertain journal quality?

Tags: publications, journals, peer-review, disreputable-publishers, reputation

I found some discussion on how one should avoid journals on Beall's list.

Related: [How do you judge the quality of a journal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-you-judge-the-quality-of-a-journal)

I wish to know about other such lists to ascertain good journals.

Specifically, is [ABDC 2013](http://www.abdc.edu.au/pages/abdc-journal-quality-list-2013.html) a good list to assess journal quality ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

It depends what you mean by '*quality*'.

I would argue the very notion of **ranking journals as this list does is deeply unsound** [see [Brembs, Button, Munafò (2013)]](http://journal.frontiersin.org/article/10.3389/fnhum.2013.00291/abstract). The quality of content in most academic journals is variable. Great articles can be found amongst the mediocre, and likewise mediocre articles can hide in issues full of high-quality articles.

Journals are a lazy proxy for the evaluation of 'quality' of content.