# How do I know that journal is good apart from the impact factor?

Tags: publications

My boss asked me to submit my research to a journal I've never heard of. 
How do I know that journal is good for my career apart from the impact factor? 
I would like to have my own criteria without just doing whatever my boss says. For example, how the journal is peer-reviewed, time of publication, specific topics, other authors, and how to measure these things just looking at a journal site.

Comment: Do you trust your boss? If so, his word is good enough. If not, why are you working under him?

Comment: What about checking if it contains papers that are relevant in your field? Either by looking at the contents of that journal or by looking how often that journal is cited in your field.

Comment: Heavily related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-you-judge-the-quality-of-a-journal

Comment: @Allure, I don't think "his" word, assuming my boss is a man, is enough. I believe is good to learn and double check as an independent person and not just do whatever my superior said. I know she will listen if I have something to say. Science is collaboration too.

Comment: @RamonaUcelay why don't you ask her why she thinks the journal is good then? She is not going to say something incontrovertible - you can double-check whatever she says then.

Comment: With repect to the whole discussion about predatory publishing, I think this question is perfectly valid and important.

Comment: @Allure. Of course, I asked her reasons to publish in that journal but I would like to have my own criteria: how is peer-reviewed, time of publication, specific topics, other authors, and how to measure these things just looking at a journal site. Maybe I didn't explain myself at the very beginning. Just reading your recommendation now. Thanks

Comment: Where do your most admired authors publish in?

Comment: @allure: sorry, but this is a very naive question. As a postdoc, you may be forced to move every 1,5 years and start a new lite in another country. I would not advice anyone to cease to work after a few months just because they don't trust their boss's suggestions about journals. You will not get far with this move.