# If a journal is not listed in Journal Citation Reports, is that a bad sign with respect to its quality and/or legitimacy?

Tags: journals

The journal *[Advances in Applied Energy](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/advances-in-applied-energy)* is not listed in *[Journal Citation Reports](https://jcr.clarivate.com/jcr/home)* (at least as far as I can tell), although its sister journal, *[Applied Energy](https://www.journals.elsevier.com/applied-energy)*, [is](https://jcr.clarivate.com/jcr-jp/journal-profile?journal=APPL%20ENERG&year=2020).

Should I be concerned about the quality and/or legitimacy of *Advances in Applied Energy*?

(I'm also having difficulty locating an impact factor for *Advances in Applied Energy* anywhere -- not just in *Journal Citation Reports*.)

Comment: I've never heard of JCR...it's a new name. Looking quickly at the editorial board, the journal seems very legit.

Comment: The journal can be new and did not have time to appear the JCR.

Comment: "Advances in Applied Energy" seems to exist solely to comply with Plan S and similar open access mandates.  https://www.coalition-s.org/

Answer (score 1):

This journal seems very new; the first issue was published in Feb 2021, so not even a year old.

There is little meaning to calculating an impact factor for such a new journal, as impact factor is a measure of the average number of citations that publications in that journal collect. If a journal has no papers older than a year, they are unlikely to have collected many citations. Consider that to count as a citation of a paper, someone has to have read the paper, done research, submitted the paper for publication, potentially gone through multiple rounds of revision and/or resubmission, and finally waited for the submission to be published and indexed by whatever service is monitoring citations. Sometimes citations are added later in the process (e.g., to update on the current state of the field which may have changed since the project started), but even then the only step you can skip is "do research"; all the steps after that can still take a year or more.

This site won't review specific journals for quality, but you can use the guidelines in this Q&A to judge for yourself:

[How do you judge the quality of a journal?](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/101/how-do-you-judge-the-quality-of-a-journal)